# PDF Generation using Rotativa.NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, rotativa

I am working on .net core 1.1 and needs to generate the pdf using Rotativa.NetCore.
Not able to generate using ViewAsPdf and ActionAsPdf.

Comment: This is also not working for me, and I'm using it in the most basic approach provided by the Rotativa samples.  When using ActionAsPdf, it completely skips the specified action and returns an unhandled exception error of "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key".

Comment: It is also not working for me same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading `Rotativa.NetCore` project from [github page](https://github.com/aaxelm/Rotativa.NetCore) and fixing the bug myself. In Rotativa.NetCore project, in `AsResultBase.cs` file I changed line 158 to:

```
if (cookieOptions.Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieOptions.Value.CookieName))
```

Then I included Rotativa.NetCore project into my solution and turned off generation of NuGet package on build for this project (Project properties -> Package tab -> Generate NuGet package on build).